# In XAML how to say: default width and height for e.g. TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, font-size, autosize

So I'm coming at WPF from a HTML perspective.

I just want to put a `TextBox` on my Window like this:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="theName" />
</Grid>
```

Turns out that the `TextBox` is then HUGE, covers the whole window. (!)

Ok, that's not what I want, but I don't want to define the EXACT size either since I know `Height` and `Width` should be flexible, so I try:

```
<TextBox Name="theName" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
```

Same thing. So I try:

```
<TextBox Name="theName" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Same thing. So I just hard code the sizes:

```
<TextBox Name="theName" Width="100" Height="20"/>
```

Which I know is not a good programming practice in WPF.

So, what how do you tell `TextBox` to "display default sizes for the font size being used"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take Bryan's example even a bit further.  By specifying a specific alignment that isn't stretch and further constrain the TextBox so that it won't expand beyond a certain size. eg:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        MinWidth="15" MinHeight="20" MaxWidth="500" MaxHeight="50"/>
</Grid>
```

You can take it even further by setting up rows/columns inside the Grid and constraining them in various fashions.  As you're coming from an HTML background, think of it like using a table to control layout.  Remember that you can also nest other container objects (i.e. StackPanels, WrapPanels, other Grids, etc...).

The challenge with XAML and the WPF/Silverlight controls is that they a very flexible, so you've got to get a handle on all the options and how they affect layout.

Good luck.  I'm going through this exact same thing now.

Answer (score 6):

Use a different container.
The Grid always streches its child controls to fill the grid cell.

You could use e.g. a stackpanel which only streches its controls in one direction.

Comment: Just a point of warning.  While a StackPanel only stretches child controls in one direction, unless you constrain that child object explicitly, then the StackPanel provides those child objects with infinte space in that direction.  Can lead to unusual side-effects with some controls.

Comment: `The Grid always streches its child controls` - that's not true, you can set the alignment to something other than `stretch` as written in the other answers.

Comment: @Bip901 yes, NOW you can do that. The question was asked 12 years ago so there have been some changes to the Grid :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to using a different panel as Stefan mentioned you could just give the TextBox an alignment that isn't Stretch. e.g.

```
<TextBox Name="theName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The sizes in WPF aren't pixels, they are "device independent pixels"  that are 1/96 of an inch - so in today's normal DPI setup they map 1:1 to pixels.

But, if you run the program in high DPI mode the TextBox will grow with the DPI (and the font).

So setting an hard-coded size isn't that bad.

Other than that you can only use HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment that are not "Stretch", this will size the TextBox to content - but then an empty TextBox will be tiny.

You can set VerticalAlignment to "Center", "Top" or "Bottom" to get automatic height of about one line (maybe backed up by a MinHeight setting to avoid problems really tiny fonts) and then set the Width so the TextBox width does not change as the user types into it.